# react-router-dom не рендерит компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Всем привет. Route не рендерит переданный в нее компонент Landing. Ради интереса передавал в этот роут компоненты Navbar и Footer ситуация аналогичная.

Версия: "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"

Вот App.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

 import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar'
 import Footer from './components/layout/Footer'
 import Landing from './components/layout/Landing'

 import './App.css'

 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar/>
    <Route exact path= '/' Component= {Landing} />
    <Footer/>
  </div>
  </Router>
)
 }
}

 export default App
```

Есть идея использовать react hooks и сделать компонент Layout функциональным и в роуте передавать его не у пропс component = {} а у render = {}, но все же хотелось бы найти решение с использованием Layout как классового компонента и передавать его в роут как component = { Layout }

Answer (score 0):

Все довольно просто, атрибут Component с большой буквы написан, а надо с маленькой